# Deploying to Azure linux webapp shows container error on port 8080

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, containers

I'm trying to deploy a simple .netcore webapp on azure linux app service and I'm getting the below error:
ERROR - Container  for site  has exited, failing site start
ERROR - Container  didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

This is a v5.0 .net and deploying the app through azure devops yaml pipeline.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp" {
  name                       = "appname"
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  service_plan_id            = data.azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  https_only                 = true

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
 site_config {
    always_on          = true
    
    #container_registry_use_managed_identity = true

    application_stack {
      dotnet_version   = "5.0"
    }
  
    use_32_bit_worker       = false
    vnet_route_all_enabled  = true 
    tags                    = local.all_tags
    app_settings = {
     "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"   = azurerm_application_insights.appinsights.instrumentation_key
    
 }
}
```

Comment: if you are using a custom container then you need to explicitly mention the port using `WEBSITES_PORT` to `8080` in the `app_settings` .[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#how-do-i-specify-port-in-my-linux-container-) let me know if that works

Comment: I'm not using any custom container and this port is taking automatically, in fact I'm using WEBSITES_PORT to 443 and that is not being taken anywhere.

Comment: What Jayendran was trying to say is that if your container is listening on port different from port 80, you need to set the port number as the WEBSITES_PORT value in application settings.

Answer (score 0):

- I was able to deploy the Azure Linux Web App without any issues

> ERROR - Container for site has exited, failing site start ERROR - Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080,failing site start

Thank you  @Jayendran for the comment,

- The ports supported by Azure Web App service are 80 and 443 , if we want to run on any other port we need to add the ***WEBSITES_PORT***   in ***Application Settings*** in Configuration  Section
- Add the value of the port number as whatever your application is listening. As per the error you need to add ***8080***

Even the same is suggested by [@SnehaAgrawal-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/168746/container-didn39t-respond-to-http-pings-on-port-80.html)

- Also we can set/change  the port in ***server.js*** file

```json
const myport= process.env.port || 8080;
```